# How do I render an HTML h1 with a Button in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am NOT a ReactJS advance or a master, and I need help in something weird...

I am trying to render in ReactJS a button, that if pressed, will render up an h1 element. I tried countless times to do this, but i never succeded....

I'll show you my code for now, please fix it in the comments...

```js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Button = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function () {
        return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
    },
    
    render: function () {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Press Me</button>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I hope you will reply to me. I'm in desprate need of help, some logical assistance will be needed here. Thanks.

Comment: Please go through this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a piece of state which will control of the header need to be shown or hided. Something as follows:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
      
      this.state = {
       toggleHeader: false
      }
    }
    
    render () {
        return (
         <div>
           {this.state.toggleHeader ? <h1>Hello World</h1> : ""}
           <button onClick={() => this.setState({toggleHeader: !this.state.toggleHeader})}>
             {this.state.toggleHeader ? "Hide header" : "Show header"}
            </button>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

[Here is also the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/3043/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a base case so I advise You to get some tutorials or better read documentation.

```
class Button extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super();
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
                    isActive: false
        }
    }
    handleClick(){
            this.setState({isActive: !this.state.isActive})
    }
    render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Press Me</button>
                {this.state.isActive? <h1>Hello World</h1> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/81695/